# General procedures and tips for solving dependency problems (Debian, Lenny)

Tags: debian, dependencies

I'm more or less as good a sysadmin as my serverfault rep mirrors. I have to upgrade a Debian (lenny) server with Plesk control panel. Plesk is supposed to manage that but the upgrade over the control panel doesn't work and I read and hear that this is often the case.

So I have to do it manually and now I'm running into seemingly circular dependency problems...

I get a lot of messages like this:

```
psa-updates depends on sw-cp-server (>= 1.0-6); however:
  Package sw-cp-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing psa-updates (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

My sources.list is up to date and working, `apt-get clean` and `apt-get update` works fine and completes without errors.

What are the correct ways of solving such problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your previous install/update was interrupted/unsuccessful. You need to check a few things:

1. That your apt sources list points to a valid server and has the necessary packages there on the server. This ensures that you will be able to update and install packages.
2. That your local apt-cache is up-to-date. Do a `apt-get update` on your system. This ensures that apt can find your updates. Sometimes, it looks for an older package that no longer exists on a system.
3. Do a `dpkg -a --configure` in case a previous install/update was interrupted. If a previous one was interrupted, there might still be some unsolved configuration problems that prevent new packages from installing successfully.

Hope it works. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Points 1 and 2 I'm familiar with and issues with these have been resolved. Point 3 is new and I will look into it right away!

Comment: Issuing `dpkg -a --configure` results in `Starting SWsoft control panels server... stale pidfile. failed` and a whole bunch of previous errors, as posted in the original question.

Comment: Oh, sounds like the SWsoft control panel server needs to be restarted. You might get away with just deleting the pidfile manually and stopping/starting the service manually. Then, repeat the dpkg process.

Comment: Can you give me a hint about where to find that pid file?

Comment: They're typically in `/var/run` directory.

Comment: yes, that's where they are :) I deleted the pidfile of SWsoft but still the same problem. In the meantime my research has shown that this could be a problem with openssl, but even downgrading openssl didn't resolve the situation.

Comment: ...and got further with this now: http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-101127.html

Comment: it wasn't openssl, it was a problem with several plesk control panel instances running and blocking tcp:10001. problem resolved.